# C# UWP SpeechRecognizer problems

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, uwp

I am developing UWP and want to use SpeechRecognizer. It should react only to words "Next" and "Back". But often, it recognizes "NExt" as "Back". My code is below. How to solve this?

```
var defaultLanguage = SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage;
        _speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(defaultLanguage);
        _coreDispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        var constraintList = new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(new List<string>() { "Next", "Back" });
        _speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(constraintList);

        var result = await _speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        if (result.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
        {
            _speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;
            _speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
            await _speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
        }
```

Here is ResultGeneratedEvent:

```
private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        {
            await _coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {

                string command = args.Result.Text;
                Messenger.Default.Send(new VoiceReactMessage(command));
                switch (command)
                {
                    case "Next":
                        SetHorizontalOffset(-ItemsPanelRoot.ActualWidth);
                        break;
                    case "Back":
                        SetHorizontalOffset(ItemsPanelRoot.ActualWidth);
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you've hit the struggles of working with speech recognition and there will be times when it can't recognize exactly what you've said.

One of the things I would recommend is taking advantage of the the [Confidence level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedphrase.confidence(v=vs.110).aspx) which you get as part of the result. Using the confidence, you can decide whether you want to accept the result or attempt to ask the user to repeat what they said.